# How to get information about checkbox using itext7 library?

Tags: java, itext7

I need to get information about `Checkbox` for instance, checkbox mark(cross, circle, etc.), checked, unchecked and so forth. But I couldn't understand where this information has kept if in this file no `XFA` information. This file has been created via `Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 19.21.20049`. I tried to find out this information using `pdfbox tool`, but I didn't find it. That is a screenshot of checkbox information:
[image]

Can anyone explain to me how to get this information and where I must find it?

Comment: You say PDFBox did not provide the information you required, but for structures like in your screen shot PDFBox usually does recognize the form fields properly. Thus, either you did something wrong in your code using PDFBox, or there is something fishy about your PDF hindering PDFBox from returning the data, or the "and so forth" you want contains information not provided by PDFBox. Thus, please share the actual PDF (so we can check our advice) and explain that "and so forth". And if you are interested why your PDFBox code did not work, additionally share that code.

Comment: @mkl I using ```itext7 7.0.4``` library and I need to get information about checkbox(checked, unchecked), mark type(cross, circle, etc.) but pdf files which created in ```Adobe Acrobat``` not contains ```XFA``` and I don't know how can I get this information another way. Can you help me?

Comment: Please decide whether you want to use itext or pdfbox. Whether it is displayed as a cross or a circle can be seen in the appearance stream, so it is tricky.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I using ```itext 7.0.4``` library. ```PdfBox``` it is just a tool that parses pdf file and shows its structure like in a screenshot above.

Comment: Seems you wrote your own PDFDebugger application. Or is this an older PDFBox version and you _were_ using PDFBox PDFDebugger? Because the current PDFDebugger looks much nicer.

Comment: @John *"PdfBox it is just a tool that parses pdf file and shows its structure like in a screenshot above."* - No. [*Apache PDFBox®* is a Java PDF Library](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), just like iText. The tool you mention merely is based on the library PDFBox and distributed as part of it. iText also has such a tool, RUPS, distributed as a separate artifact by the iTextPdf people.

Comment: @mkl thanks for your explanation. I didn't know it.

Comment: I wonder if this question can be deleted, isn't the topic answered by the other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *any* `PdfFormField field` with a value you can retrieve that value like this:

```
PdfObject value = field.getValue();
```

In case of a checkbox field this will return a `PdfName`. For an unchecked field, the name is **Off**. For a checked field it can be anything else even though the specification recommends **Yes**.

---

The appearances of these states are more difficult to determine because at least for the checked state a checkbox must provide an appearance stream containing instruction to create a visualization.

We have analyzed one such stream [in response to your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104446/1729265). In that case a ZapfDingbats tick symbol was used and you could apply text extraction to the stream and determine this.

In other cases, e.g. in case of a crossed check box, usually only vector graphics instructions are used.

It also is possible, though, to use a bitmap image here which may show anything.

Thus, while you can of course compare the appearance stream with the standard appearances generated by e.g. Adobe Acrobat and so identify the appearance of many checkbox fields, you won't be able to automatically identify all.