# How to understand pdf forms flags?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I read pdf structure using `pdfbox` and I can't find out some data from stream:

```
1 g
0 0 18 18 re
f
0.5 0.5 17 17 re
s
q
1 1 16 16 re
W
n
0 g
BT
/ZaDb 14.532 Tf
2.853 4.081 Td
13.9943 TL
(4) Tj
ET
Q
```

It is stream information about checkbox but what does it mean that letters?
Can anyone explain to me or it would be better if you can share with me where I can read about it?
[image]

Comment: See the PDF specification, in the segment "operator summary".

Comment: By the way, why did you tag your question [tag:itext] and [tag:itext7] while you said you retrieved the data using PDFBox? [tag:pdfbox] would have been apropos instead. And as the question essentially is about the format PDF, [tag:pdf] would have been great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1 g                 --- select DeviceGray WHITE as non-stroking color
0 0 18 18 re        --- define a 18×18 rectangular path, lower left at 0,0
f                   --- fill the path with the non-stroking color
0.5 0.5 17 17 re    --- define a 17×17 rectangular path, lower left at 0.5,0.5
s                   --- stroke the path with the stroking color
q                   --- save graphics state
1 1 16 16 re        --- define a 16×16 rectangular path, lower left at 1,1
W                   --- intersect the current clip path with the just defined path
n                   --- don't draw the path
0 g                 --- select DeviceGray BLACK as non-stroking color
BT                  --- begin text object
/ZaDb 14.532 Tf     --- select font with name ZaDb at size 14.532
2.853 4.081 Td      --- move text insertion point by 2.853,4.081
13.9943 TL          --- set leading to 13.9943
(4) Tj              --- draw the string with one character with character code 0x34 (what you display as "4" is the byte 0x34)
ET                  --- end text object
Q                   --- restore graphics state
```

Which character has the character code 0x34, depends on how **ZaDb** is defined. You should be able to find its definition in the font resources of the form XObject you focus on.

Quite likely, though, **ZaDb** is a ZapfDingbats font with ZapfDingbats encoding, see ISO 32000-2 annex D.6. In that case the character code 0x34 corresponds to ✔.

In other words, your form XObject draws a square with black edges and white insides, and then draws a black tick inside that square.

Comment: 8 = cross; 4 = checkmark; H = star; u = diamond; n = square, l = dot

Comment: @mkl thanks, but can you give me a link for this ```ISO 32000-2 annex D.6``` pdf file? Sorry, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf That's not 32000-2, but it still helps.

Comment: @John - ISO 32000-2 has to be bought. A copy of its precursor ISO 32000-1, though, has been published by Adobe on their web site, Tilman provided the link there. I had part 2 open here, so I looked it up in the current PDF specification.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for your help! Can you tell me where in this pdf32000_2008 located description of these characters (8 = cross; 4 = checkmark; H = star; u = diamond; n = square, l = dot)?

Comment: @mkl thanks for your help! I try to find the answer to my question for more than two one weeks!

Comment: It is indirectly mentioned in "D.6 ZapfDingbats Set and Encoding". Checkmark = octal 064 = 0x34 = "4".

Comment: Be aware that there may be other appearances. For the cross, Adobe often uses pure graphics, i.e. no "ZaDb" there. See also the "CreateCheckBox.java" example from the source code download, which shows how to create such fields.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr can you tell me where I could download "CreateCheckBox.java" example?

Comment: In the source code download, or here: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java?view=markup

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I've read some pdf file and find some strange stream which have been included into ```checkbox``` form field, look it:  ```(!) Tj```. What does it mean this ```(!) ``` symbol?

Comment: If this is Zapf Dingbats (ZaDb) then it would be a scissors symbol. But why don't you look yourself in Adobe Reader?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes, it is Zapf Dingbats (ZaDb). I looked in my Adobe reader and it is not a scissors symbol, in my Adobe reader it is still ```checkmark``` symbol but now the color is blue. And I decide to ask you about that maybe you are known about that.

Comment: Maybe that one uses a font subset, or a different font. In that case you'd have to look at it with PDFDebugger. (And it gets really tricky if you want to decode this programmatically).